# Ordenar por Fechas un List y agregralos a columnas del DataGrid C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, lista, datagrid

Quiero poblar un Datagrid con toda la informacion de un mes, dividido en 4 semanas por fechas en el mismo datagrid.
El query que tengo me regresa toda la informacion del mes y lo paso a un List, ese List lo recorro con un foreach para ir llenando al datgrid pero yo quiero que en las dos primeras columnas aparezcan los datos y las fechas de la semana 1 del mes.
En la 3er y 4ta columnas quiero la semana 2 del mes y la fecha y asi sucesivamente hasta terminar, entonces mi data grid es como el siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public class ListItems
    {
        public string Folio { get; set; }
        public string TPagos { get; set; }
        public string Fecha { get; set; }
    }
    public class ObjectList
    {
        public List<ListItems> DatosMensuales { get; set; }
    }
var resultjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectList>(responseText);
foreach (var item in resultjson.DatosMensuales)
                {
                    int filaadd = grillaContabilidad.Rows.Add();

                }
```

[EDITADO]
Ejemplo de salida de datos como quiero que quede:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me queda del todo claro el resultado que esperas obtener, podrías hacer un pequeño ejemplo con información entrada -> salida?

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue una imagen de salida como quiero los datos.

Comment: mas alla de que tenes dos respuestas interesantes, vos armas el json que recibis? podes agregar la semana directamente al json que viene? y luego solo recorrerlo ordenado? parece un problema que se puede resolver mas facil si tenes acceso a esa parte.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar tu problema, bastaría con agrupar tu información por semana.

Para hacerlo, yo uso una pequeña extensión para obtener el primer día de cada semana, y de esta manera, tener el criterio de agrupado

La extensión es la siguiente:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45040266/5213794)

---

Dicho esto, voy a armar un pequeño ejemplo de como deberías realizar el agrupado, para que puedas aplicarlo en tu caso particular.

Asumamos que tenemos la siguiente clase:

```
public class ListItems
{
    public string TPagos { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }        
}
```

Y una lista con la siguiente información:

```
List<ListItems> Lista = new List<ListItems>
    {
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,01), TPagos = "1000"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,01), TPagos = "4560"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,04), TPagos = "456"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,07), TPagos = "45"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,08), TPagos = "251"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,11), TPagos = "100"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,14), TPagos = "100"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,16), TPagos = "100"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,18), TPagos = "100"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,21), TPagos = "45"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,23), TPagos = "6565"},
    new ListItems { Fecha = new DateTime(2019,01,25), TPagos = "676"}
};
```

Utilizando Linq, podemos fácilmente agrupar la información para obtenerla en el formato que buscas, podríamos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Agrupo usando la extensión que mencione antes
var result = Lista.GroupBy(c => c.Fecha.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday))
                        //Genero un objeto anónimo
                        .Select(c => new
                        {
                            //Primer día de la semana
                            PrimerDiaSemana = c.Key,
                            //Todos elementos ubicados dentro de esta semana
                            Fechas = c.ToList()
                        });
```

Ahora, dentro de `result` tenemos la información que buscabamos, si la mostramos de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i = 0; i<result.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Semana número {0} (comenzada el {1})", i+1 ,result.ElementAt(i).PrimerDiaSemana.ToShortDateString());
                foreach(var fecha in result.ElementAt(i).Fechas)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fecha: {0}, Pagos {1}", fecha.Fecha.ToShortDateString(), fecha.TPagos);
                }
            }
```

Obtendríamos el resultado que esperabamos:

> ```
> Semana número 1 (comenzada el 31/12/2018)
> Fecha: 1/1/2019, Pagos 1000
> Fecha: 1/1/2019, Pagos 4560
> Fecha: 4/1/2019, Pagos 456
> Semana número 2 (comenzada el 7/1/2019)
> Fecha: 7/1/2019, Pagos 45
> Fecha: 8/1/2019, Pagos 251
> Fecha: 11/1/2019, Pagos 100
> Semana número 3 (comenzada el 14/1/2019)
> Fecha: 14/1/2019, Pagos 100
> Fecha: 16/1/2019, Pagos 100
> Fecha: 18/1/2019, Pagos 100
> Semana número 4 (comenzada el 21/1/2019)
> Fecha: 21/1/2019, Pagos 45
> Fecha: 23/1/2019, Pagos 6565
> Fecha: 25/1/2019, Pagos 676
> ```

De esta manera, ya tendrías la información formateada, sólo restaría, añadirla a tu `DataGridView`

Te dejo un [dotnetfiddle con el ejemplo funcional](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SnqRyL), éxitos.

Comment: Aunque tiene mucha logica tu ejemplo no me reconoce StartOfWeek me dice: 'System.DateTime' no contiene una definición para 'StartOfWeek' y no se puede encontrar un método de extensión 'StartOfWeek' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'System.DateTime' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: @Manny es lo primero que explico en la respuesta, `StartOfWeek` es el método de extensión, copia la clase que esta al principio, y/o importa el `namespace` y va a funcionar, espero tus novedades!

Comment: @Manny fijate también en el dotnetfiddle que esta de ejemplo al final

Comment: es justamente lo que hago, pero no veo el namespace en los ejemplos.

Comment: @Manny el namespace lo tenes que definir vos.. sino ponelo en el mismo que esta la clase donde estas trabajando..

Answer (score 0):

Para conocer las semanas de una fecha podrias agregar el uso de `GetWeekOfYear()` a la clase

```
public class ListItems
{
    public string Folio { get; set; }
    public string TPagos { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }

    public int DayOfWeek 
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Fecha);

            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
            Calendar calendar = myCI.Calendar;
            return calendar.GetWeekOfYear(fecha, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces con la ayuda de linq podrias agrupar los datos

```
var result = from item in resultjson.DatosMensuales
             group item by item.DayOfWeek into g
             select new {
                Semana = g.Key,
                Fecha = string.Join(", ", g.Select(x=> x.Fecha))
             };
```

asi tienes las semana y la lista de fechas donde caen cada una

Comment: que es la variable myCI @Leandro